# Call multiple web services simultaneously with NSURLConnection

Tags: nsurlconnection

Can multiple webservices be called with one connection simultaneously using NSURLConnection?

Or do I have to create a connection for each call?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to create a `NSURLConnection` object for *each request*. Once the `NSURLConnection` object is finished, it cannot be reused - as opposed to the `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: How can the NSURLRequest be reused?

Comment: Just keep a reference to the `NSURLRequest` object. When you create a new `NSURLConnection` object passing the `NSURLRequest` as a parameter, `NSURLConnection` will create a _deep copy_ of the specified request. The "original" request will not be modified, and you can reuse it when creating a new connection object.

Comment: Thanxs for answering. Would you know how can I make multiple webservices calls at the same time? Let say I need to call two services at the same time when I load a viewcontroller.